# Ramification and reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ a local field ($K$ finit extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$), $\mathcal{O}_K$ the integer of $K$ and $k$ the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Let $\psi:\mathbb{P}^1_K\to\mathbb{P}^1_K$ a finit separable morphism, $\widetilde{\psi}=\Psi:\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}\to\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ a model of $\psi$ that is $\Psi$ is the extension of scalar of $\psi$ ie $\Psi=\psi\times_{\mathcal{O}_K}\text{Id}_K$.
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}^1_K @>{\psi}>> \mathbb{P}^1_K\\
@VV{\alpha}V @VVV \\
\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K} @>{\Psi}>> \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}
\end{CD} $$
Let $\overline{\Psi}=\Psi\times_{\mathcal{O}_K}\text{Id}_k$ the reduction of $\Psi$.
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}^1_k @>{\overline{\Psi}}>> \mathbb{P}^1_k\\
@VV{i}V @VVV \\
\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K} @>{\Psi}>> \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}
\end{CD} $$

If the branching points (ie ramification points)  $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ of $\psi$ are $K$-rationnals, as $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}(\mathcal{O}_K)=\mathbb{P}^1_K(K)$ (by mutliplication of denominators) one can take their reductions $\overline{P_1},\ldots,\overline{P_n}\in\mathbb{P}^1_k(k)$.

**Question**: I'd like to prove that if the ramification indices of the $P_i$ are resp. $e_i$, they are the same for the $\overline{P_i}$ and if there are ``coalescence'' then the ramification indices of the resulting ramification point $\overline{Q}$ is the sum of the indices $e_i$ for which $\overline{P_i}=\overline{Q}$. I don't have the beginning of an explanation of that, if it's true...

I guess that we shouldn't have wild ramification so the sums of $e_i$ of point that collapse in the same point shouldn't be nul in $k$.

I guess that a general reference for that is SGA1 (Exposé X) but for the moment it's to difficult for me... If someone has a simpler reference for my specific case I'l take it! Thanks!

If you find this question to easy for mathoverflow feel free to answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769654/ramification-point-and-reduction) in mathstackexchange and tell me in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your setting, you can just do everything concretely using the derivative.

The correct statement is for $\overline{Q}$ in $\mathbb P^1_k$,
$$e(\overline{Q}) + \operatorname{swan}(\overline{Q}) = 1 + \sum_{\substack{ i \in \{1,\dots n \} \\ \overline{P}_i = \overline{Q} }} (e_i - 1).$$

This is under your assumptions except that we need to assume $\overline{\Psi}$ is separable.

To prove this, first we can assume by a change of variables that $\overline{\Psi}(\overline{Q}) \neq \infty$. Then express $\widetilde{\psi}$ as a rational function $f$ in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$, without a pole at $\overline{Q}$, and thus without a pole at any of the $P_i$ that reduce to $Q$. Now consider its derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$.

In characteristic zero, this function vanishes exactly at the ramification points $P_1,\dots, P_n$, and its order of vanishing at $P_i$ is $e_i-1$.

In characteristic $p$, its order of vanishing at a point is $e$ plus the Swan conductor minus $1$.

Now we just need to know that the order of vanishing of $\frac{df}{dx}$ at $\overline{Q}$ is the sum of its orders of vanishings at $P_i$ for all the $P_i$ that reduce to $Q$. This follows from factoring the numerator of $\frac{df}{dx}$ into linear factors, and noting that the order of vanishing is the number of linear factors that vanish at a point.

We can't rule out wild ramification here, as the example $x^p-x$ (for $K = \mathbb Q ( p^{1/(p-1)})$) shows. In that case we have one point $\infty$ with $e=p$ and $p-1$ points (the $p-1$st roots of $p^{-1}$) with $e=2$, that all reduce to $\infty$, and in the reduction, $\infty$ has $e=p$ and $\operatorname{swan}=p-1$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me in short words what is the Swan conductor or give me a reference?

Comment: @Macadam In this case we can just define the Swan conductor as the order of vanishing of the derivative minus $e-1$, which is $0$ in the case of tame ramification and $>0$ in the case of wild ramification.

Comment: Any reference on Riemann-Hurwitz in characteristic $p$ should explain what you need here, because it's mostly the same ideas.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity, but In a simple exemple, $P=x^2(x-3)^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_3$, one hase $P_1=0$ and $P_2=3$ with $\overline{P_1}=\overline{P_2}=\overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$, $e_1=2$, $e_2=2$ and the resulting ramification is $4$ because $\overline{P}=x^4$, correct? But I can't see it with your formula?

Comment: @Macadam The derivative of $x^2 (x-3)^2 = 2 x (x-3)^2 + 2 x^2 (x-3) = 2x (x-3) (2x-3)$. There is a third ramification point $3/2$ which also has $e=2$.

Comment: Ok and $3/2$ is $[2:3]$ so reduce to $[2:0]=[1:0]$ in $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_3}$. So we have 3 points $0$, $3$ and $3/2$ which goes to $\overline{0}$ all with $e=2$ and $e(\overline{0})=4$ because the function becomes $z^4$ which is coherent with $1+(2-1)+(2-1)+(2-1)$.

Comment: I need some details with the reasonning with the rationnal function $f$: I'm agree that we can write $f=\pi^k P/Q$ with $\pi$ an uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_K$, $q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $P,Q\in\mathcal{O}_K[X]$ primives and prime between them so $\widetilde{\psi}$ has a sens (not as rationnal function but with $(\pi^k P,Q)$ or $(P,\pi^kQ)$ global section generating the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(d)$). So it has a sens to reduce $f$ in the residue field $k$.

Comment: But I see two problems with that: if $q\neq 0$ the resulting reduced morphism is $(0,\overline{Q})$ or $(\overline{P},0)$ which is constant (should I add the hypothesis $\overline{\psi}$ not constant?). Second problem: what if the points are not in $\mathcal{O}_K$: they are in $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ and not $\infty$ but they should be for example $[1:u/\pi]$ and so we can not reduce the linear factor $(X-u/\pi)$ in $f'$.

Comment: @Macadam If $\Psi$ is a well-defined morphism on $\mathbb P^1_{\mathcal O_K}$ then $\overline{\psi}$ cannot be constant (using that $\psi$ is finite, thus surjective.)  For instance because $\overline{\psi}$ is a map from a projective variety, hence proper, so its image is closed. If the points are not in $\mathcal O_K$ (i.e. reduce mod $\pi$ to $\infty$) you get factors like $(cX -1)$ for $c \in \mathcal O_K$ and the same argument works. Alternately, you can extend to a larger field, which gives you enough freedom to change the variables so that none of the points reduce to $\infty$.

Comment: For the 1st pb: the fact that the image is closed is not contradictory with the constancy of the map, or I missed something? For the second pb: factors like $(cX-1)$ can reduced to $-1$ if $c\notin\mathcal{O}_K^*$ so disapear in $f'$. Maybe all this stuff work if the reduction is good? If we enlarge the field the $u/\pi$ becomes $u/\eta^q$ and the problem stay. Excuse my naive questions...

Comment: @Macadam It is contradictory with the map being surjective in characteristic $0$ and constant in characteristic $p$ (then, what is the image? Is it closed?) The factors disappearing is OK, it just means the ramification points are going off to infinity. The field enlargement is to make a sufficient linear change of variables (rational linear transformation in $X$) that the points don't go off to $\infty$.

Comment: 1st pb: I'm agree if you mean that the image of $\Psi$ is closed: the points of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{K}$ are not closed in $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ so the image of $\overline{\varphi}$ contains points of the closure of points of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ so $\overline{\varphi}$ is not closed. For the 2nd: Ok! I'd so like to have better algebraic tools in disposal so I don't have to use equations for the morphism $f$...

Comment: @Macadam If you look at proofs of Riemann-Hurwitz you will see the more abstract tools that are needed.

Comment: A last think (I promise) it's important for my (master) thesis: for me there was always unique a morphism $\Psi:\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}\to\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}$ such that $\psi$ was its extension of scalar with the trick $f=\pi P/Q$ as I said upper. But here you telled me that $\Psi$ may be not well defined: I can't see why because in all cases $\pi^k P$ and $Q$ are coprimes ($P$ and $Q$ are coprime and primitives so $\pi^k P$ ans $Q$ stay coprimes...) What's the problem? There are global sections generating the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathcal{O}_K}}(d)$?

Comment: @Macadam The issue is the morphism will not be well-defined at the vanishing points of $Q$  mod $\pi$ since $\pi P$ and $Q$ both vanish there. In general, for a morphism $a/b$ to be well-defined we want the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$ to be the unit ideal.